# Implement "Database per user pattern" in CouchDB (Cloudant <-> PouchDB)

Tags: node.js, pouchdb, cloudant, auth0

Can anyone provide me a simple example how to implement the "Database per user pattern" in CouchDB (Cloudant <-> PouchDB)? The users get authenticated with Auth0 (jwt). I'm not able to find something regarding this topic.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

here is a [sample register/sign-up application](https://github.com/glynnbird/onedbperuser) using the "one database per user" pattern. you can review it's [approach](https://github.com/glynnbird/onedbperuser/blob/master/app.js#L34) to help you get started.

however, you may want to consider [cloudant-envoy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudant-envoy) which allows your client side code can adopt a "one database per user" design pattern but stores all the users' data in one large database preventing the proliferation of databases.

Comment: cloudant-envoy seems interresting. But it's not clear to me how to integrate it with Auth0.