# Creating new user in Cloudant and Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, couchdb, pouchdb, cloudant

As I'm moving from CouchDB to Cloudant and since there is no _users database in Cloudant what are the best practices of creating a new user using POST/PouchDB authentication and updating user document with some data eg. login time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implement "Database per user pattern" in CouchDB (Cloudant <-> PouchDB)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39385757/implement-database-per-user-pattern-in-couchdb-cloudant-pouchdb)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use CouchDB style users with Cloudant databases, see [Enabling the _users database with Cloudant](https://docs.cloudant.com/authorization.html) section of the authorization docs. However there are also solutions such as [envoy](https://github.com/cloudant-labs/envoy) which can help out.